# Why can't I access my method?

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract

I have a class

```
public abstract class BoardLocation 
{
   //...
}
```

and another...

```
public abstract class Property extends BoardLocation
{
   public abstract int getRentAmt(); 
}
```

and finally, another...

```
public class Lot extends Property
{
    @Override
    public int getRentAmt()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

In my Driver.java I'm doing...

```
BoardLocation board[] = new BoardLocation[2];
board[0] = new Lot();
board[1] = new Lot();
```

but when I try to call...

```
board[0].getRentAmt();
```

I get that "Can not find symbol" and it says that board[0] is a BoardLocation.

Any reason this might be? Or any fixes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- you need to add that method,.getRentAmt, to BoardLocation. Perhaps make it an interface.
- Another option is to cast board[0] to Lot or Property, then call getRentAmt

Comment: I tried casting and it didnt work. Would i want to make BoardLocation an interface?

Comment: show thecode and the error you get. i would make boardlocation an interface.

Answer (score 1):

The static type of the elements of the array is `BoardLocation`. `getRentAmt()` is not defined for this type. The individual elements may indeed be more specialized, but via the super class reference, you are restricted to methods declared on the super type.

If you need compile time access to this method, the array either needs to be of a more specialized type (`Property[]`) or the method needs to move into the super class. Other options may present themselves if you include more information.

Answer (score 1):

Because `getRentAmt()` method is not declared in `BoardLocation` class. Your elements type is `BoardLocation` and compiler doesn't know that actually there are `Lot`s in your array. Compiler knows that you have an array of `BoardLocation` and if you want to use `getRentAmt()` method you have to declare it in `BoardLocation` and then override it in inherited classes.

Comment: so, is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

BoardLocation  doesn't know the methodd  declared in Property!
Try:

```
Property board[] = new Property[2];
board[0] = new Lot();
board[1] = new Lot();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your actual problem is poor OOP design. Try to define again what you are trying to solve and consider using an interface.

Comment: Take a look at this link, it might make things more clear for you:
[link](http://www.codestyle.org/java/faq-Abstract.shtml)